# How to set value on forms.ChoiceField in django view?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

This is my form :

```
class ch_form(forms.Form):
    ch_field = forms.ChoiceField(
        required=True , label= 'ch_field : ' , 
    )
```

and this is my view :

```
def testView(request):
    form = ch_form(
                initial={
                    'ch_field':[
                        (1, 'test1'),
                        (2, 'test2'),
                        (3, 'test3'),
                    ]
                }
            )
```

But its not work.
So my question is how can I set value for [`forms.ChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/fields/#choicefield) in view function during the runtime.

sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to set the choices in the forms `__init__()` method, maybe like this:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    ch_field = forms.ChoiceField(
        required=True,
        label= 'ch_field')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        my_choices = kwargs.pop('my_choices')

        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['ch_field'].choices = my_choices
```

And then call it like this:

```
def testView(request):
    form = MyForm(
        my_choices=[
            (1, 'test1'),
            (2, 'test2'),
            (3, 'test3'),
        ],
        initial={
            'ch_field': 2,
        })
```